# Problema con PHPEXCEL

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, phpexcel

Hola estoy teniendo problemas con mi proyecto, ya que lo migramos de PHP 5 a 8 y hemos estado actualizando librería, actualmente me está saliendo el siguiente error

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "ZipArchive" not found in PHPExcel\Classes\PHPExcel\Writer\Excel2007.php:220

donde la linea tiene la siguiente

$zipClass = PHPExcel_Settings::getZipClass();
$objZip = new $zipClass();

de antemano gracias

Comment: PHPExcel está descontinuada; se recomienda el uso de Phpspreadsheet, completamente compatible con PHP 8

Comment: Hola Jose, ¿que sistema operativo estas usando?